# Get a list of suppliers ordered by the earliest of their "has many" insurance expiry dates

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to provide a filter that sorts businesses (that "has many" contracts) by their earliest insurance expiry date.

I've tried:

```sql
SELECT
    sc.supplier_id,
    b.business_name,
    MIN(c.insurance_expiry) as contract_expiry
FROM ph_supplier_completed sc
    INNER JOIN ph_business b ON sc.supplier_business_id = b.business_id 
    LEFT JOIN ph_supplier_insurance c ON sc.supplier_id = c.supplier_id
ORDER BY
    sc.supplier_id DESC
```

But that doesn't appear to be right - although it does give me the earliest expiry date in its respective column it only returns 1 row when I have 1800~ suppliers and 1700~ have insurance records

I need a list returned that contains those 1800~ suppliers, with a column that shows the earliest insurance expiry date (if they have one)

Comment: You forgot to add `GROUP BY sc.supplier_id`

Comment: You forgot to sort the results by ANYTHING even VAGUELY resembling a date, let alone a renewal date!

Comment: @RiggsFolly unix timestamp... (was not my choice)

Comment: Nothing wrong with a unix timestamp, specially if you actually order the results of the query on it

Comment: *"But that doesn't appear to be right - although it does give me the earliest expiry date"* This query should not even execute as it does not make anny sense ANSI/ISO SQL standards wise.. As the query has aggregate functions and no GROUP BY clause, it cannot have nonaggregated columns in the select list which it has...  see [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html) it is all in there.

Comment: think about it how can `sc.supplier_id,
    b.business_name,` relate to `MIN(c.insurance_expiry) as contract_expiry` as there is no relationship between that?

Comment: @RaymondNijland but it's successfully grabbing the earliest expiry date when each supplier has a minimum of 3 insurances (liability, indemnity, workcover)

Comment: i call that extrem luck, as you are using invalid SQL here..You are playing russian roulette as the columns `sc.supplier_id,   b.business_name` values are nondeterministic (randomly) choosen

Comment: Appreciate your concern but if it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT sc.supplier_id, b.business_name,
        MIN(c.insurance_expiry) as contract_expiry
FROM ph_supplier_completed sc JOIN
     ph_business b
     ON sc.supplier_business_id = b.business_id LEFT JOIN
     ph_supplier_insurance c
     ON sc.supplier_id = c.supplier_id
GROUP BY sc.supplier_id, b.business_name
ORDER BY contract_expiry;
```

In most databases, including the more recent versions of MySQL with the default settings, your query would simply fail with a syntax error.

It is an aggregation query (because of the `MIN()`), but the first two columns are not aggregated and not in a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: Sorry to be pickie but should that not be sorted on `c.insurance_expiry` as OP wants _ordered by by their earliest insurance expiry date_ even though they didn't make that obvious attempt themselves

Comment: @RiggsFolly . . . It is ironic that the OP does mention that and then doesn't even attempt it in the query.

Comment: Add `b.business_id` to the group by.  Almost certainly, they would want different b rows to be separate, even if the name is the same.

Comment: I made that mistake in the post but have ordered correctly now, thanks